# Change font family for input type submit

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to change the font family of an input field that will be used to submit a form. the HTML markup is generated from contact form 7, and using the `::placeholder` pseudo class I was able to change the font family and the color of the placeholder that is inside the other form fields. At the moment I have this markup

```
<input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit has-spinner" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send request">
```

I've tried using CSS to apply the font family I need but it's ignored

```css
#submit-button {
    font-family: "Maiden Orange", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('...');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#submit-button::hover {
    border: none;
    background-color: transaprent;
}
```

Is there any other solution I can apply?

Comment: What does it means "the HTML markup is generated from contact form 7, and using the ::placeholder pseudo class I was able to change the font family and the color of the placeholder that is inside the other form fields."? What is contact form 7? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @MarcoMerola contact form 7 - if you click on that tag it will tell you what it is, a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: How are you loading the font, and are the other styles applied?

Comment: This code looks fine. So the problem isn't this code. Maybe these styles are being overridden by other styles ... you can use your browser inspector to see which styles are being applied and which are being overridden. Or maybe your styles aren't being loaded by the page for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this and work from there.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maiden+Orange&display=swap');

#submit-button {
  font-family: 'Maiden Orange', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em 0;
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Elementor wasn't loading thefont in that page. I've discovered this by looking at the imported fonts, I've used your suggestion and I was able to load the desired font. Thank you for the tip